# C i cant read binary file properly

Tags: c, file, io, binary

Hello i have a structure with couple of variables and i try to write and read them from/to binary files but when i read them i see only strange symbols and i dont know what i messed up,i have tried couple of variants but none of them works

```
    typedef struct catalog
    {
        char num[20];
        char name[80];
        char author[50];
        double price;
        int year;
        char publisher[80];
    } Catalog;

    Catalog* createCatalogData()
    {
        Catalog* c = malloc(sizeof(*c));
        if (!c)
        {
            // Ups... add error handling
            exit(0);
        }

        printf("Add num ");
        getString(&c->num);

        printf("Add name ");
        getString(&c->name);

        printf("add author ");
        getString(&c->author);

        printf("Add price ");
        if (scanf("%lf", &c->price) != 1)
        {
            // Ups... add error handling
            exit(0);
        }

        printf("Add publisher");
        getString(&c->publisher);

        printf("Add year");
        if (scanf("%d", &c->year) != 1)
        {
            // Ups... add error handling
            exit(0);
        }

        char *filePath = malloc(strlen(c->num) + 13);
        char *folderName = "Catalogs\\";
        strcpy(filePath, folderName);
        strcat(filePath, c->num);
        strcat(filePath, ".bin");

        FILE *file = fopen(filePath, "wb");
        if (file == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error opening file!\n");
            exit(1);
        }


        fwrite(&c->num,1, strlen(c->num), file);
        fwrite(&c->name,1, strlen(c->name), file);
        fwrite(&c->author,1, strlen(c->author), file);
        fwrite(&c->price, 1, sizeof(double), file);
        fwrite(&c->publisher,1, strlen(c->publisher), file);
        fwrite(&c->year,1, sizeof(int), file);

        fclose(file);

        return c;
    }

    Catalog* readCatalogData(char *filePath)
    {
        Catalog* c = malloc(sizeof(*c));


        FILE* fh;
        fopen_s(&fh, filePath, "rb");
        //check if file exists


        char *ptr;
        //read line by line
        const size_t line_size = 300;
        char* line = malloc(line_size);
        int counter = 0;
        char* date;

        fread(c->num, 1, 21, fh);
        fread(c->name, 1, 80, fh);
        fread(c->author, 1, 50, fh);
        fread(&c->price, 1, sizeof(double), fh);
        fread(c->publisher, 1, 80, fh);
        fread(c->year, 1, sizeof(int), fh);

        return c;
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `&` in `&c->num` etc. when writing.

Comment: i have changed that and still dont work properly, but it gives me error if price is without &

Comment: `malloc(strlen(c->num) + 13)` off-by-one error.

Comment: I strongly suggest you read about pointers and how/when arrays are treated as pointers.

Comment: Did you consider using [JSON](http://json.org/)? You won't have *binary* (but textual) files, and you can easily find good libraries to parse them.

Comment: I must do it with binary files

Answer (score 2):

When you do e.g.

```
fwrite(&c->num,1, strlen(c->num), file);
```

you write a variable number of bytes without any terminator. When you read the file you have no idea how many bytes to actually read.

The above `fwrite` call actually contains *another* error, in that you write a *pointer* and not the actual data in `c->num`.

Instead of writing the data members one by one, write the whole structure in one single call:

```
fwrite(c, sizeof c, 1, file);
```

And when reading the file read the whole structure in a single `fread` call.

---

Important note (and as noted by Attie in a comment): If you intend to make this portable, then you should use [*serialization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) to read and write the data, as the size of the structure might not be the same on all platforms.

For simple code and just "experimenting" then it will work fine.

Comment: @HristoVutov Then you're doing something else wrong. Writing/reading the whole structure should work fine.

Comment: It is only okay to write structures to disk if you are 100% sure that the packing will not change from build-to-build, and you are 100% sure that the file won't be accessed on another architecture. In short. Do not do this.